# C++ gcc large number errors

Tags: c++, gcc, double

My c++ project needs to work with numbers of planet masses... up to over 24 digits. They are floats. The same variable may also be a relatively small number (100) I have tried using double, and long, but compiling in linux with G++ I am receiving the warning: warning:

integer constant is too large for its type [enabled by default].

Also my calculations do not work because of this. I am wondering what type variable this kind of number will require.

I have done research, but it's turned up dry.. still, my apologies if this question is frequent. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add some sample code? Thanks!

Comment: *They are floats* -- So why are you using an integer rather than the obvious  `float` or `double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a piece of code like:

```
double mass = 31415926535892718281828459;
```

then you need to understand that the *constant* is an integer. The whole statement would turn it into a `double` before putting it into `mass` but your scheme is failing *before* that point.

You need to tell the compiler it's a double straight away with something like:

```
double mass = 31415926535892718281828459.0;
```

Section 2.14 of `C++11` details the literals and how they're defined. A group of digits, where the first isn't `0`, is captured by the following rule of section `2.14.2 Integer literals`:

```
decimal-literal:
    nonzero-digit
    decimal-literal digit
```

(a group of digits starting with `0` is still an integer, just one made out of octal digits rather than decimal ones).

Section `2.14.4 Floating literals` shows how to instruct the compiler that you want a `double` such as, for example:

- including a fractional component as in `1.414` or `15.`; or
- using the exponent notation as in `12e2`.

Or, for the language lawyers out there:

> A floating literal consists of an integer part, a decimal point, a fraction part, an e or E, an optionally signed integer exponent, and an optional type suffix. The integer and fraction parts both consist of a sequence of decimal (base ten) digits. Either the integer part or the fraction part (not both) can be omitted; either the decimal point or the letter e (or E) and the exponent (not both) can be omitted.
>
> The type of a floating literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify float, the suffixes l and L specify long double.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure it is double:

```
123456789012345678   // integer, give warning
123456789012345678.0 // double (floating point)
```

If you need extra precision, you should consider using a large number library. See also [C++ library for big float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694877/c-library-for-big-float-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple test case that produces this warning:

```
float foo() {
  return 1000000000000000000000000;
}
```

The problem is that the number written there is actually an integer literal.  This code is basically saying "take this value as an `int`, convert it to `float`, and return that."  But the number is too big to fit in an `int`.

Solution:  add ".0" or ".0f" to the end of the number to make it a `double` or `float` literal instead of an `int`.